# mPDF name as a variable?

Tags: php, variables, mpdf

So i got this doc that is converted to .pdf using mPDF. But I cant seem to figure out how to change the name of the .pdf file by using a variable.

Right now mPDF uses this code to generate the .pdf and the name which here is just plain "filename.pdf"

```html
$mpdf->Output('filename.pdf','D');
```

But i need the name to use a variable so the name is uniqe each time.
I got the variable $counter that has a number that changes with each pdf, and i would like that to be the name og the .pdf combined with the variable $date

So that the name of the pdf would be somthing like 1852-12-03-2015.pdf

Any way to make this possible with mPDF?

Comment: It must not use a random number. It has to use the mumber from the variable $counter. And the $date might aswell be a name... So it really needs to be a combination of 2 variables

Answer (score 1):

try this..
`rand(1000,9999)` used for generating random number of 4 digits

```
$mpdf->Output(<?php echo rand(1000,9999).'-'.date('d-m-y').'.pdf'; ?>,'D');
```

Comment: It must not use a random number. It has to use the mumber from the variable $counter. And the $date might aswell be a name... So it really needs to be a combination of 2 variables

Comment: @KristianTarp and please clear this thing in your questions.. so the answerer can serve you with better answers.. thanks